# Validate TFS 2017 Boolean field

Tags: tfs

I am trying to edit work item templates to make use of the new Boolean field in TFS 2017, and want a particular field to be set to true before a status can be changed. Is there any way to do this? It would appear ALLOWEDVALUES and MATCH aren't supported, which could have potentially helped

Comment: I presume you are talking about Team build in TFS 2017 and not the XAML builds? The way I resolved this problem is to use a inline Powershell task that validates input fields

Comment: I am talking about work item templates fields, sorry. I'll edit to make that clear

Comment: Got it!. The only way you can do what you want is to create a conditional rule. Check out the conditional rule https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/assign-conditional-based-values-and-rules

Comment: That's what I have e tried, as stated in the original post. Unfortunately the ones that would seem to fit don't work for a Boolean field

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by applying a conditional rule based on your requirement just as Hamid mentioned above.

`Boolean` is just a data type, we can add a custom **Boolean field** and add a checkbox for it.

1. Use the following syntax to add a Boolean field within the FIELDS
   section of the WIT definition.

   `<FIELD name="Triagelc" refname="lc.Triage" type="Boolean" >
    <DEFAULT from="value" value="True" />
           <HELPTEXT>Triage work item</HELPTEXT>
    </FIELD>`
2. And then add the following syntax within the FORM section to have
   the field appear on the form.

   `<Control Label="Triagelc" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="lc.Triage" />`

   The field will appear as a checkbox on the form.
3. Then apply a `When` rule for target filed, thus when the specified
   Boolean field has the specified value, the `When` rule is applied to
   the target field.

## eg1:

Apply a "When" rule for `Description` field in Task work item type :

```
<FieldDefinition name="Description" refname="System.Description" type="HTML">
  <WHEN field="lc.Triage" value="True">
    <REQUIRED />
  </WHEN>
</FieldDefinition>
```

Then when set the value to **True**, the Description area is **required**, it cannot be empty.

## eg2:

You can also use **READONLY** rule to restrict other areas:

```
<FieldDefinition name="Assigned To" refname="System.AssignedTo" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension">
  <WHEN field="lc.Triage" value="True">
    <READONLY />
  </WHEN>
  <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
  <HELPTEXT>The person currently owning this task</HELPTEXT>
</FieldDefinition>
```

Thus, when the Boolean field value is **True**, `Assigned To` field is read only, otherwise you can assign to the existing users.

---

**UPDATE:**

## eg3:

We can not achieve that directly with the boolean data type. As a workaround you can try below ways:

- Apply the `When` rule and embed the `Copy` rule (Copy `True` as the
  value) for the "Triagelc" boolean field in this example. Thus when
  the status is Done, **Triagelc** can set the value to "True"
  automatically, then save. But in this way the value still can be
  modified to false. Reference below screenshot 1:

  `<FieldDefinition name="Triagelc" refname="lc.Triage" type="Boolean">
    <WHEN field="System.State" value="Done">
      <COPY from="value" value="True" />
    </WHEN>
    <HELPTEXT>Triage work item</HELPTEXT>
  </FieldDefinition>`
- Set the default value to **True** for Boolean field (**Triagelc**
  field in this example), then apply `When` rule with `READONLY` rule
  embedded. This way should be meet your requirement (Once done the value cannot be changed anymore). Reference below screenshot 2:

  `<FieldDefinition name="Triagelc" refname="lc.Triage" type="Boolean">
  <DEFAULT from="value" value="True" />
  <WHEN field="System.State" value="Done">
  <READONLY />
  </WHEN>
  <HELPTEXT>Triage work item</HELPTEXT>
  </FieldDefinition>`

Please note that:

> The Boolean data type field is only supported for VSTS and TFS 2017.2
>   and later versions.

Screenshot 1:
[image]

Screenshot 2:
[image]

Comment: My issue that s slightly different. My issue isn't that another field is needed when a Boolean field is true, but rather the Boolean field must be true before the status can change

Comment: @StevenBrookes Confused me, is that similar as example 2 mentioned in above answer? Could you shown an example?

Comment: Your example 2 says when Triagelc is true, set the description to readonly. I want it so that when the status is Done, Triagelc cannot be false

Comment: @StevenBrookes Based on the rules, seems we cannot achieve that.

Comment: That's a shame. I can work around it with reverting to a yes/no dropdown, but was looking forward to using a dedicated field type to control it. Is this something that could be addressed in future a release?

Comment: @StevenBrookes I figure it out, please see the updated answer, example3. It should be the closest workaround to achieve that.

Comment: Not quite what I need unfortunately, though I do have a Boolean field on my forms which does that (auto switches to true on status change). The field needs to be set to true by someone as it is essentially part of a checklist that will be shown on the form, so the reason it needs to validate the value is to confirm the checklist is complete. I did try having a hidden Boolean field which was frozen at false, and used the NOTSAMEAS validation, but that didn't work. I could do something similar with a hidden dropdown with true/false values...but then I may as well just have a Yes/No dropdown :P

Comment: @StevenBrookes Unfortunately that's not supported for now, you could submit a user voice to suggest the feature in this site: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services